# Swift 3 is adding 6 hours to any time I store in a variable?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm using swift 3 in Xcode 8, and I'm trying to do some simple work with some times. But just working with some sample times, whenever I store a time in a variable and then print to console, Xcode is printing the time + 6 hours. Here is the code I'm using

```
let alarm1Time, alarm2Time, alarm3Time: Date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    alarm1Time = dateFormatter.date(from: "12:00")!
    alarm2Time = dateFormatter.date(from: "11:59")!
    alarm3Time = dateFormatter.date(from: "06:30")!
    print(alarm1Time)
    print(alarm2Time)
    print(alarm3Time)
```

and the result I'm getting in the console is

```
2000-01-01 18:00:00 +0000
2000-01-01 17:59:00 +0000
2000-01-01 12:30:00 +0000
```

I don't know why it's adding 6 hours to the time, and it's messing up the work I want to do.
And also, can someone tell me how to get rid of the date when I store a time? Like if I just wanted to have

```
18:00:00
```

stored as the time.
Thanks!

Comment: It's timezone related

Comment: Do you know how I could go about fixing that?

Comment: The date is correct. `print` prints the dates in UTC

Comment: Oh so the date is being correctly stored, but it only gets altered when i print it? so in other words all the work I want to do with the variables will be correct?

Comment: Set the locale.